# How to import files which has nested namespace in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm converting an existing Node.js project to be fully TypeScript-based. I previously had a static `Sql` class (an object with sub-objects containing MySQL helper functions). An example would be `Sql.user.findById`. The `Sql` class also had a `query` function for executing raw MySQL queries without needing to expose the underlying MySQL connection.

What I would like now is a namespace named `Sql` containing the `query` function, and then in the files that used to contain the sub-classes, I would like namespaces such as `Sql.User` that export functions like `findById`.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to nest namespaces like this while being able to access `query` in the nested namespaces.

Right now what I have is this:

`sql.ts`:

```
import * as connection from "./connection";

export * from "./queries/confirmEmail";
export * from "./queries/resetPassword";
export * from "./queries/user";

namespace Sql {
    export function query( ...args: any[] ) {
        return connection.query( args );
    }

    export class Errors {
        static confirmCodeExpired = "45001";
        static confirmCodeNonExistent = "45002";
        static userAlreadyConfirmed = "45003";
    }
}
```

`./queries/resetPassword.ts`:

```
import "../sql";

namespace Sql.ResetPassword {
    type InsertCodeArgs = {
        code: string;
        userid: number;
        canChange: boolean;
    }

    export function insertCode( args: InsertCodeArgs, cb: Nodeback<void> ) {
        Sql.query(
            "CALL insert_reset_code( :code, :userid, :canChange );",
            {
                code: args.code,
                userid: args.userid,
                canChange: args.canChange ? 1 : 0
            },
            cb
        );
    }

    export function removeCode( code: string, cb: Nodeback<void> ) {
        Sql.query(
            "DELETE FROM `resetcodes` WHERE `code` = :code;",
            { code: code },
            cb
        );
    }

    export function checkCodeValid( code: string, cb: Nodeback<boolean> ) {
        Sql.query(
            [
                "SELECT NOW() <= `c`.`expires` AS `valid`, `c`.`canchange` as `canchange`, `u`.`id` AS `userid` FROM `resetcodes` AS `c` ",
                "INNER JOIN `users` AS `u`",
                "ON `u`.`id` = `c`.`userid`",
                "WHERE `code` = :code LIMIT 1;"
            ].join( " " ),
            { code: code },
            ( err, data ) => {
                if ( err ) return cb( err );
                if ( !data || data.length === 0 ) return cb( null, null );

                return cb( null, data[ 0 ].valid > 0, data[ 0 ].userid, data[ 0 ].canchange > 0 );
            }
        );
    }
};
```

When I try and compile, however, I get a number of errors that look like this:

`src\sql\queries\resetPassword.ts(11,13): error TS2339: Property 'query' does not exist on type 'typeof Sql'.`

How can I "backreference" the query function from the parent file? I can't `import { Sql } from "../sql"` of course, because then `Sql` is a duplicate definition, and I get an error that `src/sql/sql.ts has no exported member "Sql"`.

Comment: just wondering why you use namespaces instead of modules?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use modules in the TypeScript sense, so if that would be a better way to do it, I'm all ears.

This is all in one "module" in the Node sense (one package.json for the entire project); I'm thinking more along the lines of namespacing in the C# sense I suppose, where there would be a sub-namespace containing all the SQL code.

Comment: can you also post you existing `node.js` code in `js`? I'll take a look tomorrow

Comment: I've already converted it, but I can go grab that file from my git history.

Comment: Ok, here's the old Node.js JavaScript code.

https://gist.github.com/briman0094/d6cca72e3dce25ee80fbdfd8bf14eac7

Comment: Ok, so I got it compiling (and am now able to reference the parent namespace in the sub-namespaces), but I don't know how to "merge" the namespaces into one now. I'm going to create a new question with a new focus.

Answer (score 5):

I solved my namespace referencing problem by alias-importing the parent namespace in the child namespace files:

```js
import { Sql as sql } from "../sql";

...

namespace Sql.User {
    export function ... {
        sql.query(...);
    }
}
```

This allows the `Sql.User` namespace to use functions in the `Sql` namespace from another file. I still don't know how to merge the namespaces into one so that `Sql.User` and its siblings can be imported simply by importing `sql.ts`. I need to create another question for that.